# Sum values if multiple conditions met in different sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one sheet that creates a mapping of names to values (Map_Sheet).  In another sheet there are values for each name in the mapping table (Data_Sheet).  What I am trying to do is add values based on certain conditions in the mapping table.  For example: I want to add all counts of dog by bread and color.  So in the mapping table I would look for all dogs that are brown and of a certain bread and get their names and manually add them together.  I want to have a formula that does the addition based upon multiple conditions from Map_Sheet.

Here is an example of the data:

```
Map_Sheet-
name|bread|color|age
a     x     b     2
b     y     w     3
c     x     b     2
d     z     f     4

Data_Sheet -
id|a|b|c|d
0  3 4 2 1
1  1 2 4 2
2  3 5 7 2
3  1 2 6 9
4  1 3 5 7
```

And for each ID in the data sheet I want a count of bread X with color B.  So I would add for ID0 values for A and C, (3+2) - so ID0 = 5, etc for each id.

I cannot use VBA so I was looking into using INDEX and MATCH but I cannot wrap my head around it.  Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the row headers in the first sheet match the column headers in the second sheet, you can put this formula in (say) G2 of the second sheet.

```
=SUM(TRANSPOSE(Map!$C$2:$C$5="b")*C2:F2)
```

If the column headers in the second sheet were in a different order, you would have to use something like:-

```
=SUM(C2:F2*NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($C$1:$F$1,IF(Map!$C$2:$C$5="b",Map!$A$2:$A$5),0))))
```

Both of these are array formulae. You can add extra conditions to select breed as well as colour using the same basic pattern:-

```
=SUM(TRANSPOSE((Map!$C$2:$C$5="b")*(Map!$B$2:$B$5="x"))*C2:F2)
```

or

```
=SUM(C2:F2*NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($C$1:$F$1,IF((Map!$C$2:$C$5="b")*(Map!$B$2:$B$5="x"),Map!$A$2:$A$5),0))))
```

[image]